# How to hide scrollbars cross-browser WITHOUT destroying functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

I've got a horizontal scrollbar in use and I'd like to continue using it, but hide the scrollbar functionality. I cannot use the "overflow: hidden" method, since that will destroy the JS functionality in place. Is there any way of doing this that will satisfy all modern browsers?

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

var $panels = $j('#primary > #main > article');
var panelLeftsArray = $panels.map(function () {
    return ($j(this).position().left);
}).get();

var len = panelLeftsArray.length;
var getCurrentSectionIndex = function (left) {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (left >= panelLeftsArray[i] && left < panelLeftsArray[i + 1]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return len-1;
};

var index = 0;

var handler = function () {
    var position = Math.abs($j('#primary #main').position().left);
    index = getCurrentSectionIndex(position);
    console.log(index);
};
var scroll = function(){
    $j('#primary').unbind('scroll', handler);
    $j('#primary').scrollTo('#main article:eq(' + index + ')', 800, {
        axis: 'x',
        onAfter: function () {
            $j('#primary').bind('scroll', handler);
        }
    });
}
$j('#primary').bind('scroll', handler);

$j('.control_next').click(function (e) {
    console.log(index);    
    if (index < len-1) {
        index++;
        scroll();
    } 
    return false;
});

$j('.control_prev').click(function (e) {
    console.log(index);
    if (index > 0) {
        index--;
        scroll();
    }
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pilgrimish/pB3rB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want the scrollbar to show, but not to do anything, just trigger the scroll event without doing the true scroll, so you can position the viewport at the beginning of a section?

Well, there's no way to do this. You can't disable the scrallbar functionality and still show it. However, you could set overflow-x to 'hidden'. The, create a fixed div attached to the bottom of the window with the exact height of a scrollbar and the width of the browser window. Inside it, create an inner div with 0 height and the same width as the parent document. You'll have to handle the resize event to adjust the scrollbar div.

Then, attach your scroll handler to the scroll event of the scrollbar div, and use the scroll position to scroll manually the main document.

I'm doing some guess, because in you jsfiddle the scrollbar acts like a normal scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry, Oscar. The sentence should have read: I've got a horizontal scrollbar in use and I'd like to continue using it (functionally), but hide the scrollbar.

Comment: What you mean, then, is that you don't want to see the scrollbar, but you want the 'prev' and 'next' buttons to work like they do right now, to jump between sections?

Comment: Just use 'oveflow-x: hidden'. I've tried it and the buttons work. Overflow hidden tells the browser not to show scrollbars, but you can still scroll with Javascript.

Comment: That's sweet. How could I retain the ability to scroll with a trackpad?